# Export browse window to MS Word using Stata asdoc

Tags: ms-word, export, stata, stata-macros, asdoc

How can I export the contents of the Stata `browse` window to MS Word?
I'm currently using the `asdoc` command. However, any method outside "copy and paste" is acceptable.

my attempt

```
ssc install asdoc, replace
sysuse auto

asdoc, row( make, price, mpg, rep78, headroom, trunk, weight, length, turn, displacement, gear_ratio, foreign ) title(Test Table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below to export the current dataset or its subsets to MS Word

```
ssc install asdoc, replace
sysuse auto
asdoc list make price mpg rep78 headroom trunk weight length turn displacement gear_ratio foreign in 1/10 , replace
```

to export without inputting the variable names

```
asdoc list * in 1/10 , replace
```

and to export the entire dataset, simply remove the `in`

```
asdoc list * , replace
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the `browse` window are just the current dataset, or whatever subset you specify.

Minimally, you may considering using an `export` command to create a dataset file.

For any output to be readable by MS Word, much hinges on what you might be willing to do without, or other way round, your unstated criteria on what file you expect to be produced.

The following are among details to think about:

1. `browse` respects display formats, which do not have to match the precision with which Stata holds data.
2. `browse` by default shows value labels when defined. You may wish to export values **and** value labels.
3. `browse` may have difficulty showing very long strings.
4. The dataset may include objects not shown in the `browse` window, such as characteristics.